# facebook c# sdk login problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

recently i decided to switch to the 5.0.3 verison of the facebook c# sdk library. One of the modifications a i had to do was to change the script in my login view :

```
FB.init({ appId: '<%: FacebookContext.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
```

which was previously something like `Facebook.FacebookSettings.Current.AppId` and it used to work fine. Now i get the compilation error

> S0103: The name 'FacebookContext' does
>   not exist in the current context

My webconfig is set correctly i think, just like in the mvcwebsite sample included in the library. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register **Facebook** namespace in the page or via web.config.

Or you could manually type the full namespace:

```
'<%: Facebook.FacebookContext.Current.AppId %>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that
  `@Facebook.FacebookContext.Current.AppId`
is now
  `@Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId`